# C# Does chaining multiple LINQ method calls enumerate a collection multiple times?

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have the the following code:

```
var myList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var newList = myList.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Select(x => x * 2);
```

Does `myList` get enumerated over twice (i.e. once for the `Where` and once for the `Select`), or does it only enumerate once? More generally, when chaining n LINQ method calls, does the collection being selected from only get enumerated once, or n times?

Comment: For `Select` and `Where` once only. The iterators returned from those methods yield items one by one.

Comment: Only once - that's a very important part of the way that Linq works.

Comment: You probably wouldn't have thought to ask the question if you'd been using the actual "LINQ"y syntax - `var newList = from a in myList where a%2==0 select a*2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends but in your example no.

LINQ has a concept of *deferred* operations. These only evaluate when the enumeration happens. These are like `.Where()` and `.Select()`

*Immediate* operations are like `.ToList()` that cause a full enumeration.

You can read up on them here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution

Comment: Deferral isn't the only issue. `GroupBy`, for example, is also deferred, but would cause duplicate iteration when chained before other LINQ methods.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay fair enough i do think the microsoft docs do give more detail - i'm trying here to get a simplistic answer.

Answer (score -1):

No, not normally, that is the point, the result of a call to `.Where()` is simply a deferred expression. It is not until you call the enumerator that it actually enumerates, which your code is not doing at all.

After your code:

```
var myList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var newList = myList.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Select(x => x * 2);
```

`newList` is an instance of `IEnumerable<int>`, it is simply a chain of function call expressions that have not yet been evaluated, or executed.

Later in your code if you store the results into an actual list, the original list will only be iterated once, each function being executed for each item in the list in the order that they were chained in:

```
var listResult = newList.ToList();
```

This will first iterate the list as follows

1. move to the first item: `1`
2. evaluate `Where(x => x % 2 == 0)`: `false`

   - this *yields* a *break* and ends the evaluation for this item
3. move to next item: `2`
4. evaluate `Where(x => x % 2 == 0)`: `true`
5. project using `Select(x => x * 2)`: `4`
6. yield the value to the output list.
7. move to the next item: `3`...

Comment: Both `Where` and `Select` are deferred, but that doesn't explain whether `myList` is iterated twice when `newList` is iterated.

Comment: In your current code it is not iterated at all!